# services.AddDefaultIdentity with a second user type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a framework which uses the following user type:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string WizardState {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The initial ConfigureService of the startup.cs with the following statement:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The Index page (index.cshtml) run and prompts to a specific controller/action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Step1","Sample1")" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
Start Sample1
```

The specific controller/action is:

```
public class Sample1Controller : WizardBaseController
{
    public Sample1Controller(IConfiguration configuration,
     IWizardNavigatorService<WizardStep> navigatorPersistenceService) :
     base(configuration, navigatorPersistenceService)
    {

    }

    public IActionResult Step1()
    {
        return StepResult(new Step1ViewModel());
    }
```

Where `WizardBaseController` derives from `Controller`:

```
public abstract class WizardBaseController : Controller
{
 ...
}
```

When clicked to run such page I have the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Nexum.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'Nexum.Services.NavigatorPersistenceService'.

A fact is that it doesn't even run the call controller/action, as in debugging a breakpoint is inserted in the very beginning of it and it doesn't reach that point at all

Then I tried changing the `IdentityUser` in the *startup.cs* to `ApplicationUser` as:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And then, from just starting the application there was the error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

Now referring to IdentityUser...

The ApplicationDbContext is this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<AreaAtuacao> AreasAtuacao { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Criador> Criadores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DiscrecaoCliente> DiscrecoesClientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Empreendedor> Empreendedores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FaixaInvestimento> FaixasInvestimento { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Investidor> Investidores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RedeSocial> RedesSociais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StartUp> StartUps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Socio> Socios { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I'm completely lost in this...

Comment: Can you show your `ApplicationDbContext`? Did you follow [“Add custom user data to Identity”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or [“Customize Identity”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: @poke I just appended the ApplicationDbContext at the end...

Comment: You’ll need to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` in order for it to pick up your custom user class.

Comment: @poke Nope, stays the same... The errors are the same

Comment: Please show the actual part of `ConfigureServices` where you configure Identity, the database context and user entity, and the constructor of the controller where you are trying to inject the user manager. – It’s difficult to understand what combination you are currently trying when the question is “I tried X, then changed Y, and Z”.

Comment: @poke I just found what was... I posted my solution here, but thank you for the support

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in this matter but I suspect that if you call `AddDefaultIdentity` with `IdentityUser` as type parameter, it will register `UserManager<IdentityUser>`, same happens if you call it with your user type. So you can't get `UserManager` with 2 different type parameters because they are completely different types.

So you should either user one type of user and store their unique properties in some other table or do something hacky like this:

Let's suppose we have these 2 user types with unique properties:

```
public class User1 : IdentityUser
{
    public string UniqueStringProp { get; set; }
}

public class User2 : IdentityUser
{
    public int UniqueIntProp { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you call AddDefaultIdentity with the type parameter IdentityUser. You'll have a UserManager available.

In your DbContext you should write this in your OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User1>()
        .HasBaseType<IdentityUser>();

    builder.Entity<User2>()
        .HasBaseType<IdentityUser>();

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

This way you are telling EntityFramework that `User1` and `User2` are also subtypes of `IdentityUser` and it will put them into the same table (by default).

It will generate a table like this, which will have all the IdentityUser descendants:

[image]

You can create users with the `UserManager<IdentityUser>` with your unique user type, since the methods require an `IdentityUser`, `User1` and `User2` are also IdentityUsers. However when you need to access the unique data of the users you need to type-check every time, because the query methods will only give you your users as `IdentityUser`. So if you wanted to access your `User1`'s stringProp you'd have to do like this:

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("user1's username");
if (user is User1 user1)
{
    // Access user1's string property here
}
```